# How to use an array in a WHERE sql clause?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am trying to run the following php code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('connection not made');
$db = mysql_select_db('name', $con) or die('db not selected');

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID=2";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1, $con);
$sensorids = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

$query2 = "SELECT SensorID, Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN($sensorids)";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $con) or die('query not made');
$sensors = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

echo $sensors;
```

where i want to get only those sensors that have a SensorID, which is also a value in the 'sensorids' array.
When i run the code i get the following:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\...\test.php on line 10
query not made
```

When i remove the "$" as follows:

```
$query2 = "SELECT SensorID, Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN(sensorids)";
```

the notice goes away, but still, the query is not made.

Is there any problem with the format of the 'sensorids' array?

Also, is 'echo' the right way to present the array or should i use another method?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope @RobinvdA they don't have to, `implode` will do the job in one line

Comment: A proper fix would be to use a join or subquery.

Comment: .... never, ever use `SELECT * FROM` ....

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use `implode` or anything, just combine your queries

```
SELECT SensorID, Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN
(
  SELECT id FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID=2
)
```

**A note** for all the `implode` based answers:

That will only work if they select only 1 column in their first query, they are doing `SELECT *` which results in a multi-dimensional array and doesn't contain only sensor ids and hence that will fail. See the updated answer by **diEcho** to read more about that.

And use a newer and safer extension for MySQL stuff

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: First sensible suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect you can do this in 1 query, but I don't know your name of the `id` field, might be `SensorID` or something.

```
$query2 = 
  "SELECT SensorID, Variable
   FROM sensors 
   WHERE SensorID IN (
     SELECT id
     FROM nodesensors
     WHERE NodeID=2
   )";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $con) or die('query not made');
$sensors = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
```

Alternatively:

```
$query2 = 
  "SELECT s.SensorID, s.Variable
   FROM sensors AS s
   INNER JOIN nodesensors ns ON ns.id = s.SensorID
   WHERE ns.NodeID=2";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $con) or die('query not made');
$sensors = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

fixes

- `SELECT *` is wrong, select only sensorID column from `nodesensors`

  `SELECT sensor_column FROM nodesensors ...`
- Use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with glue `','` before applying it to second query

  `$id_list = implode("','",$sensorids);`
- [`Mysql IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) takes comma separated values

  `WHERE SensorID IN(" . $id_list . ")";`

Comment: You know with their code with this will never work. `$sensorids` contains the result of `SELECT *` and not just one single column. This will fail

Comment: Oh I was not ware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you are done, 
Please don't use Select * but use the only column contain senserid

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('connection not made');
    $db = mysql_select_db('name', $con) or die('db not selected');

    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID=2";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1, $con);
    $sensorids = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

    $query2 = "SELECT SensorID, Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN(".implode(',',$sensorids).")";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $con) or die('query not made');
    $sensors = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

    echo $sensors;

?>
```

Comment: Can i have a comment fron the down voter with the reason

Comment: Yes i'm the down-voter and the reason is provided on diEcho's answer. Please review

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky It was just i can know what was my fault i have updated my answer thanks :)

Comment: Ermmm that `fault` is still there :) The first query needs to be changed to select only one column.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes but i dont know the exact name of the column from his database table

Answer (score -1):

Use [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$sensorids = implode(',',$sensorids);
$query2 = "SELECT SensorID, Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN($sensorids)";
```